# how to handle multiple parameters in express routes

Tags: javascript, express, routes, handlebars.js

I am developing a website using express and routing to handle http requests.

I am populating my html div elements using handlebars:

```
<div class="popup center" style="height: 15em;">
    <h3 name="name" id="name">{{ active_name }}</h3>
    <p name="description" id='description'>{{ active_desc }}</p>
</div>
```

Now I let the user to modify that elements using *contenteditable="true"*.

With a button I would like to call a route passing all the fields that has been modified.

For now I was able to pass only one element (i.e. {{session.recipe}} that is the id of the recipe) but I would like to handle the modified name and description too.

```
<a href="/save-recipe/{{session.recipe}}" style="color: black;">
  <button name="button" class="greyishBackground width45 right">
      <p>Save</p>
  </button>
</a>
```

In the index.js I'm doing this:

```
router.get('/save-recipe/:id/', function(req, res, next) {
    var recipe_id = req.params.id; 

    console.log(req.body.name); // doesn't work - undefined
}
```

Since req.body.name is not working (it is undefined) I'm trying to find a way to pass to the route more parameters in order to handle them in the same way as I handled the recipe_id (i.e. req.params.id).

Can someone explain me how to do it? 
Can I creat an object with name and description fields and pass only the object? How can I do it?

Or there is a way to make that *req.body.name* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.get('/save-recipe/:id/:name/:desc', function(req, res, next) {
var recipe_id = req.params.id; 
var recipe_name = req.params.name;
var recipe_name = req.params.desc;
}
```

`req.body.name` is undefined because you are not posting anything to the server.

Comment: thanks! and in the href how do I need to pass the elements? I mean, how can I fetch the name content for example and pass it in the url?

Comment: Since I'm using 2 parameters for now but I would like to add more of them is there a way to create an object and pass just the object (containing all the params)?

Comment: does this link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873573/parse-post-request-from-node-js-handlebars?

Comment: I suggest you make a post request and pass the details you need to save as a payload to http post request

Comment: I would like not to use a form since I can not populate its input fields as I'm doing now when loading the page. I already tried with a form and it works but I would prefer to avoid this way for the reason above

Comment: Why you don't want to post a JSON body?